# What happens before a POST request to a C# Controller Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a page which submits a serialized form to a Controller Action:

`$.post('@this.Url.Action("MyMethod", "MyController")', $form.serialize()).done(...`

The controller method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("MyMethod")]
public async Task<JsonResult> MyMethodAsync(SomeViewModel someViewModel)
{ ...
```

I've added a parameterless constructor to my ViewModel:

```
public SomeViewModel()
{
}
```

But, in trying to step through my Controller Action (`MyMethod`), the breakpoint is never hit because of null errors in some of the ViewModel properties. I want to know:

1. Why is my parameterless constructor invoked before the Action method to which I am POSTing? I'd like to set a break point before this happens if possible
2. Why does the cursor immediately step from the parameterless constructor to the properties in the class? Is this just implicit in the flow of instantiating an instance with a paramaterless constructor?

Comment: (1)  It has to construct the view model before it can pass it to your action method.  (2) that is the order in which an object is constructed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's much easier to understand if we just see a picture:

[image]

As you can see, Model Binding (what binds the request's content to your parameters) happens **before** your action is called. Otherwise, you'd only have `null` values in your parameters.
Your second question is likely just how Visual Studio can show the deserializer working. Remember that an object must be created before you are able to alter its members.